# Tricky Excel Lookup

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I have a table in Excel that looks like this:

```
Column A    Column B   
Header
Desc 1     Value1    
Desc 2     Value2    
Total      TotalValue
```

I only know the Header name to search for but I want it return the TotalValue from Column B.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: So, You are searching the first row with the string "Total" in the A column, under the one that match the string you provide, and then get the corrisponding value in the column B?

Comment: So, exactly as I was saying, my keyword is "Header" and I want it to return TotalValue, which in comparison to header is at a column difference and 3 rows.

Comment: oh, simpler then, I'll write a sol

Comment: I have to search the file first for the position of "header", but if you know the answer let me know it, I`ll buy you a drink :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 =OFFSET(A1;MATCH("Header";A1:A5;0)+2;1)
```